# Branch protection in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to setup a GitLab project for 2 (or more) people to work on together and I considered doing it like this:

- Everyone works on his own branch and completed tasks are merged into the master branch.
- Noone can merge into the master on his own but has to create a merge request that is handled by someone else but not himself.

This way I plan to encourage that merged code is properly designed/documented, such that someone who didn't write the code can easily verify whether the commit is reasonable or not.

The question is how do I implement these permissions in GitLab Community Edition. Is it even possible in Community Edition?

Comment: Have a look here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is not possible with the GitLab Community Edition/Free Version.

In order to forbid everyone to merge their own merge requests into master, you need **the Merge approvals feature**, that is only available from GitLab Bronze and higher. Maybe it will eventually end up in CE, there is a longstanding request for it: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/42096

Currently, with the free version, you could still protect your master branch and only allow certain people to merge into master. However, those people would still be able to merge their own branches.

So, if you do not want to spend money, you would have to enforce the *no-one-merges-their-own-MRs* policy by telling people to just not do it. In principle this can work, you could e.g. say a MR is only allowed to be merged once all discussions are resolved and someone else has explicitly accepted the MR in a comment.